# Sometimes data isn't loading to CKeditor in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I have this code in angular directive.

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(element[0]);             
          ngModel.$render = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
               ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
             },350);
           };

           ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
               $timeout(function () {
                 ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
               },350);
           });

           function updateModel() {
             scope.$apply(function () {
                   ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
             });
           }

          ck.on('pasteState', updateModel);
```

But, sometimes, data that loaded via API, doesn't set up without any errors. `console.log(ngModel.$viewValue)` always show information.

Answer (score 0):

Inside [CKEditor 4 documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor) there is no "pasteState" event, only "paste". So you should probably listen to "paste" or "change" event.
Something like this:

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(element[0]);             

ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
    $timeout(function () {
     ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
    },350);
});

function updateModel() {
    scope.$apply(function () {
       ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
    });
}

ck.on('paste', updateModel);
ck.on('change', updateModel);

ngModel.$render = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
       ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
     },350);
};
```